Cannot create a Qwik QRL when creating a form
Good morning/afternoon/evening, I have been scratching my head with this throughout the course of the day, and I cannot see a reason why Qwik would exhibit this behaviour:
import { component$ } from "@builder.io/qwik";
import { routeAction$, Form } from "@builder.io/qwik-city";

export const useAccountCreation = routeAction$(async () => ({
  success: true,
}));

export default component$(() => {
  const action = useAccountCreation();

  return (
    <Form action={action}>
      <label>
        Your name
        <input type="text" name="name" />
      </label>
      <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
    </Form>
  );
});

In the browser (Chrome Canary Version 128.0.6582.0 (Official Build) canary (64-bit)) NOTE: I've replaced the actual path on my machine with 'path' so 'path%5Cnode_modules...':
<form action="?qaction=EF0CVuuKE74" preventdefault:submit="" method="post" on:submit="//%40fs/path%5Cnode_modules%5C%40builder.io%5Cqwik-city/routeactionqrl_action_submit_a5bzc7wo00a.js?_qrl_parent=path%5Cnode_modules%5C%40builder.io%5Cqwik-city%5Cindex.qwik.mjs#routeActionQrl_action_submit_A5bZC7WO00A[0 1 2 3]" q:key="0F_0" q:id="7">
    <label data-qwik-inspector="routes/test/index.tsx:13:7">
        Your name
        <input type="text" name="name" data-qwik-inspector="routes/test/index.tsx:15:9"> 
    </label>
    <button type="submit" data-qwik-inspector="routes/test/index.tsx:17:7">Sign up</button>
</form>


I imagine it's because of the %5C (**) in the form action, because the same error is replicated if I run the following code in the console:
new URL("%5C")

Please let me know your thoughts if you have any, it would be greatly appreciated.
For reference:

Qwik version (@builder.io/qwik): ^1.6.0
Qwik-city version (@builder.io/qwik-city): ^1.6.0


After even more head-scratching I realised that when I've built Qwik apps in the past, everything was fine. No complaints from the browser. So...
All I had to do was downgrade my version from the latest to the previous (stable) version:

Qwik version (@builder.io/qwik): 1.5.7,
Qwik city version (@builder.io/qwik-city): 1.5.7

Job done 
